# Ubuntu 14.04LTS RDP client supporting Hebrew

Tags: 12.04, rdp, hebrew

I'm looking for an RDP client that will support Hebrew (which I added to my system already)

Could I use the solution I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469301/ubuntu-14-04-rdp-hell) for an Ubuntu server?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

As no one has answered your question after 14 hours, I'm supposing you're not running an Ubuntu server.  (If my assumption is wrong, drop me a note @Fabby and I'll correct)

Use VNC for any GUI version of Ubuntu: it'll send graphics over the RDP link and it will work *no matter what* language you're using...

שָׁלוֹם

Comment: VNC at the side of client, or server ?

Comment: Sorry to be unclear: VNC server Remmina client (or both VNC server/client) I've been without a computer.  Please leave me a note after Friday if you want to pursue this... (Sending this from another PC)